# Another dynamic array implementation in C

Tags: beginner, c, array, cache

I saw quite a few posts about making a dynamic array so I tried making my own for learning purposes.

Here it is:

```
#ifndef VECTOR_H
#define VECTOR_H

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

#ifndef VECTOR_RESERVE_SIZE 
#define VECTOR_RESERVE_SIZE 4
#endif

//Declaration

typedef struct
{
        int size_of_each;
        int reserved;
        int used;
        void* data;
} vector_t;

bool vector_init(vector_t *, int);
void vector_append(vector_t *, void *);
void* vector_get(vector_t *, int );
void vector_set(vector_t *, int, void *);
void vector_free(vector_t *);

//Implementation

bool vector_init(vector_t *p, int s)
{
        p->size_of_each = s;
        p->reserved = VECTOR_RESERVE_SIZE;
        p->used = 0;
        p->data = malloc(VECTOR_RESERVE_SIZE * p->size_of_each);

        if (p->data != NULL) { return false; }
        else { return true; }
}

void vector_append(vector_t *p, void *d)
{
        if (p->used == p->reserved)
        {
                p->data = realloc(p->data, VECTOR_RESERVE_SIZE);
                //printf("reallocated \n");
                p->reserved += VECTOR_RESERVE_SIZE;
        }
        memcpy((void*)((char*)p->data + p->size_of_each * p->used),  // copy to back of the vector
                        d, p->size_of_each);

        p->used += 1;
}

void* vector_get(vector_t *p, int i)
{
        if (!(i > p->used))
        {
                return (void*)((char*)p->data + p->size_of_each * i);
        }
        else { return NULL; }
}

void vector_set(vector_t *p, int i, void *d)
{
        if (!(i > p->used))
        {
                memcpy((void*)((char*)p->data + p->size_of_each * i), d, p->size_of_each);
        }
}

void vector_free(vector_t *p)
{
        free(p->data);
}

#endif
```

Here is an example of its usage:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define VECTOR_RESERVE_SIZE 3
#include "vector.h"

int main()
{
        int a = 321;
        int b = 45;
        int c = 21;
        int d = 31;
        int e = 71;

        vector_t v;
        vector_init(&v, sizeof (int));

        vector_append(&v, &a);
        vector_append(&v, &b);
        vector_append(&v, &c);
        vector_append(&v, &d);
        vector_append(&v, &e);

        printf("1st element is  %d \n", *(int*)vector_get(&v, 0));
        printf("2nd element is  %d \n", *(int*)vector_get(&v, 1));
        printf("3th element is  %d \n", *(int*)vector_get(&v, 2));
        printf("4th element is  %d \n", *(int*)vector_get(&v, 3));
        printf("5th element is  %d \n\n", *(int*)vector_get(&v, 4));

        vector_set(&v, 4, &a);
        printf("4th element after setting is  %d \n\n", *(int*)vector_get(&v, 4));

        //contiguous
        printf("size of int is: %d \n", sizeof (int));
        printf("address of 1st element: %p \n", vector_get(&v, 0));
        printf("address of 2nd element: %p \n", vector_get(&v, 1));
        printf("address of 3rd element: %p \n", vector_get(&v, 2));
        printf("address of 4th element: %p \n", vector_get(&v, 3));
        printf("address of 5th element: %p \n", vector_get(&v, 4));

        vector_free(&v);
}
```

I've written some C++ before and this was one of my first few projects in C.

I'd like to know overall how good my code is and whether I'm using good practices / conventions.

Edit:

this:
`p->data = realloc(p->data, VECTOR_RESERVE_SIZE);`

should be this:
`p->data = realloc(p->data, (p->reserved  + VECTOR_RSERVE_SIZE) * P->size_of_each);`

Edit: Maybe it's too late but, if people are still reviewing this I would really like to know how does this approach compare to std::vector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Self document**

Consider users do not want to see or may not have access to the implementation and are left to declarations.

These deserve parameters names and at least a comment about what each function does and how to use.  (e.g. Call `vector_init()` first.  It overwrites all `vector_t` members.)

```
// Deserve for documentation here.
bool vector_init(vector_t *, int);
void vector_append(vector_t *, void *);
void* vector_get(vector_t *, int );
void vector_set(vector_t *, int, void *);
void vector_free(vector_t *);
```

**Think big**

Why limit to sizes up to `INT_MAX` when C readily handles sizes up to `SIZE_MAX`.  That could be billions times more.

Use `size_t` for array indexing and sizing.

```
    // int size_of_each;
    // int used;
    size_t size_of_each;
    size_t used;

// vector_get(vector_t *, int );
vector_get(vector_t *, size_t);
```

**Design: Smaller empty impact**

Consider an app making 100s or 1,000,000s instance of this `vector` (e.g. a vector of vectors).  Many of them will could be empty and never used.  This is no advantage in doing that first `malloc()` at `vector_init()` time and a wasted allocation for all those unused instances.  Allocate when needed.  IMO, `vector_init()` should not allocate anything - it does make then that function error free - an important attribute to an *initialization* function.

**Design: Slow Linear growth**

Rather than linearly grow the array (incurring O(n*n) re-allocation time), scale the new size by maybe doubling (or some factor).

**Design: Error handling**

Detect and report (re-)allocation failures.

```
// void vector_append(vector_t *p, void *d)
bool vector_append(vector_t *p, void *d)  //return true on error
```

**Design: range check**

`vector_get(vector_t *p, int i)`, `vector_set(vector_t *p, int i, void *d)` perform no range check on `i`. Live as dangerously as you please, yet I'd definitely, at least, include parameters check on `vector_set()`.

**Design: `const`**

I'd expect `const` to show that the data state has not changed.

```
// void* vector_get(vector_t *p, int i)
void* vector_get(const vector_t *p, int i)
```

**Bug: Code in header file**

Code is apparently designed for different `VECTOR_RESERVE_SIZE` depending on which .c includes it.

Unfortunately, if 2 .c files each include this, the there will be 2 `vector_init()`, `vector_free()`, etc, creating linker conflict.

Instead, divide code into vector.h and vector.c files.   I suspect though this causes trouble with the `VECTOR_RESERVE_SIZE` scheme.  IMO, `VECTOR_RESERVE_SIZE` is unnecessary.

**Corner bug**

No need to assume `vector_free()` is not called again.  Leave data in a diminished, but correct state.

```
void vector_free(vector_t *p) {
    free(p->data);
    p->data = NULL; // add
    p->used = 0; // add
}
```

**`else` not needed**

```
    if (!(i > p->used))
    {
            return (void*)((char*)p->data + p->size_of_each * i);
    }
    // else { return NULL; }
    return NULL;
```

**Odds & Ends**

`p->size_of_each * p->used` may overflow `int` math leading to UB.  Best to ensure at least `size_t` math.

`void *` not needed:

```
// memcpy((void*)((char*)p->data + p->size_of_each * p->used), d, p->size_of_each);
memcpy((char*)p->data + (size_t)1 * p->size_of_each * p->used, d, p->size_of_each);

// return (void*)((char*)p->data + p->size_of_each * i);
return (char*)p->data + (size_t)1 * p->size_of_each * i;
```

**New functions**

`int vector_apply(vector, int (*function)(void *state, void *element), void *state)` ⟶ Apply the function to each element in the vector.  Return early if not zero returned from `function`.

`vector_right_size(vector)` ⟶ Shrink the vector to the minimum needed size.

Comment: It might be worth emphasising that the documentation should indicate what the return values mean - I certainly had trouble inferring that from the code.  Also, `vector_right_size()` could be `vector_shrink_to_fit` to help anyone familiar with C++ standard containers.

Answer (score 3):

In C, as in C++, object pointers can be freely converted to `void*`, so quite a few casts can be removed.

It's probably convenient to store `data` as a `char*`, since that's how we use it.  We should still use `void*` as external interface, of course.

This is a dangerous anti-pattern:

> ```
>             p->data = realloc(p->data, VECTOR_RESERVE_SIZE);
> ```

If the `realloc()` fails, it returns a null pointer.  By overwriting `p->data` before we check for null, we leak the old value of `p->data`, which is no longer accessible.  And the null-check is also missing, so subsequent access is Undefined Behaviour.

Style-wise, I think I'd find `(!(i > p->used))` easier to read as `(i <= p->used)`.  And `if (p->data != NULL) { return false; } else { return true; }` as `return !p->data;`.

The example code should set a good example, and check the return value of `vector_init()` (and also `vector_append()` once you realise it needs to indicate success/failure) and react appropriately.  Otherwise, you'll find you're encouraging slapdash usage.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback,I have problem when I'm trying to implement those safety checks at vector_append(), I get a segfault when i try to just assert the reallocated pointer and i can't figure out why

Comment: It's obviously wrong to assert, since we know the pointer might be null.

Comment: I don't get it,  by asserting I mean this : assert(ptr != NULL);

Comment: Yes, that's why it's wrong.  `realloc()` can return a null pointer, so the assertion is wrong.

Comment: You need something more like `char *ptr = realloc(p->data, new_size); if (!ptr) return false;  p->data = ptr; …; return true;`.

Comment: Could you double-check the "as in C++"? I don't think it is correct. At least that's what I remember from 15 years ago.

Comment: @Roland, you're probably thinking of conversion _from_ `void*`, which is allowed in C, but requires a cast in C++.  The conversion to `void*` is a widening conversion and fine in both languages.

Comment: Thanks for explaining that conversion _to_ `void *` is fine. That's exactly the detail I missed and that confused me.